# Reading Excel Report to populate selected information in Access table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import relevant information from Excel report which is not specifically designed to import data. Basically it is formatted report with other information. Please see the attached image to get an idea. This is huge report and contains hundreds of rows.

I'm thinking to import data by reading Excel file reading line by line, based on the information on that particular row and then inserting that row into Access table.

I've attached simplified version of report to give you an idea about the report layout and also Access table structure, the information I want to store in table DailyTranaction.

Example Report Image here:

[image]

Access Table Structure Image here:

[image]

I'm not sure the best way to do the above task using Access VBA, a working simple example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Location is not required but report date and branch code is required.

Comment: I'm not sure how to read date as the very first row and then other information on different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert [new code module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495%28v=office.12%29.aspx) then copy and paste below code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GetDataFromReport(ByVal sRepFileName As String) As Integer
Dim xlApp As Object, xlWbk As Object, xlWsh As Object
Dim retVal As Integer, sRepDate As String, r As Integer, sBranch As String, sQry As String, rs As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_GetDataFromReport

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sRepFileName)
Set xlWsh = xlWbk.Worksheets(1) 'or pass the name, ex: "Sheet1"

sRepDate = xlWsh.Range("A1")
r = InStr(1, sRepDate, "th")
sRepDate = Replace(sRepDate, Left(sRepDate, InStr(r - 3, sRepDate, " ")), "")
sRepDate = Replace(sRepDate, "th", "")

'find the last row;
rs = xlWsh.Range("A" & xlWsh.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
r = 3
Do While r <= rs
    Select Case UCase(Trim(xlWsh.Range("A" & r)))
        Case "", UCase("CustId")
            'skip empty row and header of data
            GoTo SkipRow

        Case UCase("Branch:")
            sBranch = xlWsh.Range("B" & r)

        Case Else
            'proceed if the value is numeric
            If Not IsNumeric(xlWsh.Range("A" & r)) Then GoTo SkipRow

            sQry = "INSERT INTO Reports([ReportDate],[BranchCode],[CustId],[AccountNo],[Transaction])" & vbCr & _
                    "VALUES(#" & sRepDate & "#," & sBranch & ", " & xlWsh.Range("A" & r) & _
                            ", " & xlWsh.Range("B" & r) & ", " & xlWsh.Range("C" & r) & ")"
            'Debug.Print sQry
            DoCmd.RunSQL sQry
            'get the number of rows affected ;)
            retVal = retVal +1
    End Select

SkipRow:
    r = r + 1
Loop

Exit_GetDataFromReport:
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Set xlWsh = Nothing
    xlWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set xlWbk = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    'return value
    GetDataFromReport = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_GetDataFromReport:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_GetDataFromReport

End Function
```

To use this, you need to [create macro](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/overview-to-macros-a39c2a26-e745-4957-8d06-89e0b435aac3), which **action** should refer to above function:

```
GetDataFromReport ("C:\report.xls")
```

As you can see, you need to define full path to the source workbook.

Alternativelly, you can run above code by creating procedure:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox GetDataFromReport("D:\Report Daily Transaction.xls") & " records have been imported!", vbInformation, "Message..."
End Sub
```

Alternativelly, you can create macro which open form. [Sample database and report](https://losmac.myqnapcloud.com:8082/share.cgi?ssid=0Urq57h)

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks Maciej Los for your reply and taking time to provide a working example. I will use your code as a base to implement into my codes.
Thanks again!